# email notification not working in oracle endeca merchandising workbench when active or deactive rule

Tags: endeca-workbench

Email notification is not working or triggering for user mail addresses in oracle endeca merchandising workbench when active or deactive rule,Do i need to do any settings or configurations in any files ?
Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Endeca Does not provide OOTB mail notification of activate/deactivate rule across all versions.

Email functionality available in config xml files there you can add scrits to trigeer email.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal

Comment: I am new for Endeca, thank you very much for your answer. It would be great if you tell exact path location of config xml file where we can write email trigger script.

Answer (score 0):

Add following xml node in Dataingest.xml under config/script folder:-

```
<custom-component id="Mailer" class="com.endeca.esource.dtmailerutility.MailNotificationComponent" host-id="ITLHost">
<properties>
<property value="${mailer.smtpHost}" name="smtpHost"/>
<property value="${mailer.srcAddr}" name="srcAddr"/>
<property value="${mailer.destAddr}" name="destAddr"/> 
</properties>
<directories>
<directory name="savedMsgDir">./logs/saved_msgs</directory>
</directories>
</custom-component>
```

Then in your baseline java beanshell script you could call out something like to pass in the subject and body of the email message:

Mailer.sendExceptionMsg("Error running Baseline Update", e);

As you've probably already done, you need to make sure the Mailer .jar is on your classpath via the ./control/runcommand.bat file

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal